# How can I pass a variable-length string from an RPC server to the client?

Tags: c++, winapi, rpc, idl

I am implementing a Windows system service, which acts as RPC server, and a corresponding client, both in C++. I am using plain Windows RPC functionality.

Passing strings from the RPC client to the server is easy. Just declare the function parameter in the IDL file like this:

```
[in, string] wchar_t* myString
```

MIDL will take care of the memory-allocation magic. Works like a treat.

Returning a modified client string is also easy:

```
[in, out, string] wchar_t* myString
```

That requires me to properly size the string on the client side, though.

**Problem:**

I need to return strings from the server to the client. I do not know on the client how large they are going to be, so memory allocation on the client is not an option.

I *could* allocate a very large amount of memory, say 10K, an amount large enough for every string the server could possibly return. But that is a huge waste of resources (memory, network), and I still cannot know for certain that the server never needs to return a larger string.

**What I tried:**

Amonst many other things I tried the technique used in Microsoft's [strout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373823%28VS.85%29.aspx) sample. It worked when calling the RPC function for the first time, but crashed the server when called for the second time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The MSDN page [Multiple Levels of Pointers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374188%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) brought me on the right track. With the example and explanation given there I managed to make it work. The essentail parts are as follows:

IDL file:

```
error_status_t ReturnsString
(
   [out]                   long*     size,
   [out, size_is(, *size)] wchar_t** outString
);
```

Server function:

```
error_status_t ReturnsString (long* size, wchar_t** outString)
{
   wstring outStringWString = L"Return this to caller";

   int stringSize = sizeof(wchar_t) * (outStringWString.size() + 1);
   *outString = (wchar_t*) midl_user_allocate (stringSize * 2);
   wcscpy_s (*outString, stringSize, outStringWString.c_str());

   *size = outStringWString.size() + 1;

   return ERROR_SUCCESS;
}
```

I do not know why the multiplication by two (stringSize * 2) is necessary, but it is. If omitted, you get instant heap corruption.

Client code:

```
wchar_t** versionRPC = (wchar_t**) midl_user_allocate (sizeof(wchar_t*));
*versionRPC = NULL;     // Required to create a unique pointer
long stringSize = 0;
DWORD retVal = ReturnsString (&stringSize, versionRPC);

// Copy the returned string
wstring stringFromServer (*rpcString);

MIDL_user_free (*rpcString);
MIDL_user_free (rpcString);
```

Comment: You are using Unicode string which are 2 bytes per char, therefore you need to multiple the string length * sizeof(wchar)...

Comment: @Remko Yes, that is correct, but I was referring to the next line, I guess: midl_user_allocate (stringSize * 2)